# Android Activity under visual studio results in "undefined reference to" when attempting to build while referencing .a library

Tags: android, c++, visual-studio, android-ndk

I have been dealing with this issue for a couple of days now. I Built the .so library using cmake under visual studio using the fallowing settings:
CMakeList.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set(ANDROID_STL c++_static)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r21d/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake)
project("GetValsDudeLib"). 


So far I have been unable to find any examples online 

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x86)

set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH arm)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME ANDROID)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "C:/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r21d")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION clang5.0)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 23) # API level
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI x86)
 

file(GLOB GetValsDudeSRC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hpp) 
add_library (GetValsDudeLib STATIC ${GetValsDudeSRC})
```

CMakeSetting.json

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "x86-Debug",
      "generator": "Ninja",
      "configurationType": "Debug",
      "buildRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\build\\${name}",
      "installRoot": "${projectDir}\\out\\install\\${name}",
      "cmakeCommandArgs": "",
      "buildCommandArgs": "",
      "ctestCommandArgs": "",
      "inheritEnvironments": [ "gcc-arm" ],
      "variables": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I added the the reference to the android native activity project:
Added headers folder path. Project properties C/C++ => Additional Include Directories.
Added library (.so) folder path. Project properties Linking => input=> Additional Library Directories.
Specified Library. Project properties Linking => input=> Library Dependencies (set that to "GetValsDudeLib").

After that I am able to create an instance of the class provided by the Library (GetValsDude) and build. It runs with no issues. But if I try to use a method of the object (AddOne(int)) it fails with the fallowing exception:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Application Type\Android\3.0\Android.Common.targets(119,5): error MSB6006: "clang.exe" exited with code 1.
1>    263 Warning(s)
1>    1 Error(s)
1>
```

Looking into the logs I found the following:

```
...
1>    C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK\android-ndk-r21d\toolchains\x86-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin\ld: Opened new descriptor 10 for "x86\Debug\libRevEngineAndroid.so"
1>     undefined reference to 'GetValsDude::AddOne(int)'
...
```

So obviously there is a failure Linking GetValsDude header to the .so library.

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Why have you set `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH` to arm, but `CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI` to x86? Which one do you want?

Comment: x86. Apologies, I was trying different value combinations. Just incase I made the correction. Unfortunately the issue persist.